# Accessing DB2-LUW 10 with entity framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, db2, entity-framework-6

I am developing an application in which the database is selected by the end user at runtime. The database can either be on a MS SQL server or an IBM DB2 server. I am currently using IBM DB2 10 Express-c on a windows server for testing. I am developing using Visual Studio 2013 C# and Entity Framework 6. I have installed the EntityFramework.IBM.DB2 Nuget package for the DB2 support. I am using reverse-engineer code-first against an existing SQL server database to generate my base code. The application works fine against a SQL Server database.

I am using System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory to generate the provider.

```
            System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder connectString = new System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder(a_Connection);
            System.Data.Common.DbConnection conn = System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(connectString.Provider).CreateConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = connectString.ProviderConnectionString;
            LB500Database = new LB402_TestContext(conn, true);
```

a_Connection is provider=IBM.Data.DB2;provider connection string="Database=LISTBILL;User ID=xxxx;Password=yyyy;Server=db210:50000"
and is being parsed correctly by the EntityConnectionStringBuilder.

I then try to access a table in the database with

```
            LBData500.LB_System oneSystem;
            System.Linq.IQueryable<LB_System> allSystem = LB500Database.LB_System.Where(g => g.DatabaseVersion == databaseVersion && g.CompanyID == companyID);
```

I get an invalid operation exception "Sequence contains no matching element" which means that no elements are returned. If I remove the Where so that all rows are returned (there is one in the table) and try to enumerate the result set using the VS debugger I see the message:
"The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe."

I am not using multi-threading. I am not inside the OnModelCreating.

Just changing the connect string to point to SQL server works fine, so I think my basic approach is sound. If I were getting some kind of error back from the server I would have something to go on. I can run the query from inside Visual Studio, so I have connectivity.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I turns out the EF objects were generated using EF5 and the EF6 runtime was being used. I regenerated the EF objects using EF6 reverse engineer code first. I can now connect to the database and get an error message:
"ERROR [42704] [IBM][DB2/NT64] SQL0204N  \"DBO.LB_SYSTEM\" is an undefined name."
The schema in the DB2 database is the same as my userid (in this case, not always). I added the CurrentSchema=xxxx to the provide connection string, but EF is still passing dbo as the schema name.

Now I need a way to change the schema name at run time. I saw a link to codeplex EFModelAdapter (http://efmodeladapter.codeplex.com). So I may give that a try.

**Update2** After looking through EFModelAdapter, I decided to take a different route. Since I only need database access and not schema management, I decided to go with Dapper (https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net). This works great for what I need and allows me to change the schema name when accessing DB2 databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my Update 2, Entity Framework was a little overkill for what I needed. I switched to dapper https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net and I am working fine against multiple DBMSs.